# Rails: How do I load my local Angular 2 app inside a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have an angular 2 app that I built using the angular cli generator: https://github.com/EdmundMai/angular-2-playing

This is the generator: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

I ran `ng serve` and now I have a page I can see when I visit `http://localhost:4002`

My dist/index.html file in the angular 2 app looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularTwo</title>
  <base href="/">

  <script src="/ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="http://carbon.ec2.crowdtap.com/component_importer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <angular-two-app>Loading...</angular-two-app>



    <script src="vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script><script src="vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script><script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script><script src="vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('main');
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>





</body>
<script>
  window.carbon.importComponents({ components: ['ct-button', 'ct-button/ct-button-link', 'ct-dialog', 'ct-progress'] });
</script>
</html>
```

In my rails view, I am trying to include these JS files:

```
<script src="http://localhost:4200/vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:4200/vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:4200/vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:4200/system-config.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:4200/main.js"></script>
```

However, it's not working and complaining that `main.ts:1Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Is there a proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `<base href="/">` tag (line 6) in the generated

dist/index.html

to `<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>`